# Angular2: How to bring up a public dialog box?

Tags: angular

**Here is dialog:**

[image: Dialog]

**Here is my code:**

[image: My Code]

It is a public function and all the post requests invoke it.
When `status == 2`，I want to show the dialog. How can I do this?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow see this link before you ask a question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey @panglisen please add some information how to open a dialog, what is code for that, you question contains less information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to include the name of the function you're calling, so more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please see [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can open a dialog using variable you just have to toggle some variables value when condition is true for status code is 2. like this.

```
....
if(status === 2 || status == "2")
   this.dialog = true
else if(this.status !== 2)
   this.dialog = false;
```

now on the basis of condition open your dialog as per the value of dialog variable.

if still any doubt please edit your question with more code.

PS: May be were stuck due to status code type, might be the case status code in number but you are comparing with string so please check it.

Comment: All of the HTTP post request calls this method,then All the page needs to contain  dialog ?

Comment: if you have a different templates than you must need a dialog for diff compnents, also you can create a modal component and call again and again at the time of post request.